# DOMPDF not open in Windows

Tags: php, html, dompdf

I have made a PDF document from PHP, but I do not open in Microsoft Widnows 7 and 8,  It has made the PDF with tables, and insert the data correctly with cycles, but in Windows this problem occurs and does not open the downloaded PDF document, I've done the test with 3 computers with Windows.

public function pdfAction() {
    require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");

```
$seguimiento = new Application_Model_DbTable_Seguimientos();
$datos_seguimiento = $seguimiento->casosReportes();
//var_dump($datos_seguimiento);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($datos_seguimiento); $i++) {
    $caso = new Application_Model_DbTable_AsuntosEstudiantiles();
```

.........continuecode...................

```
    $html = '<html><body>' .
            '<table border="1" rules="all">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="10"> TITLE</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Periodo Academico</td>
            <td>ESTAMENTO (Estudiante, Profesor, administrativo)</td>
            <td>Nombre</td>
            <td>GENERO (Femenino - Masculino)</td>
            <td>TIPO DE INDENT(c.c. - t.i. - c.ext.)</td>
            <td>NUMERO DE IDENT</td>
            <td>Codigo</td>
            <td>PROYECTO CURRICULAR o DEPENDENCIA</td>
            <td>FACULTAD</td>
            <td>Tipo Caso</td>
            <td>Observaciones</td>
        </tr>';

    $datoshtml = $datoshtml . '
      <tr>
      <td>' . $fecha . '</td>
      <td>' . $tipo_beneficiario . '</td>
      <td>' . $nombre_beneficiario . '</td>
      <td>' . $genero . '</td>
      <td>' . $tipo_identificacion . '</td>
      <td>' . $numero_identificacion . '</td>
      <td>' . $codigo_ud . '</td>
      <td>' . utf8_decode($nombre_proyecto) . '</td>
      <td>' . utf8_decode($nombre_facultad) . '</td>
      <td>' . $tipoasunto . '</td>
      <td>' . utf8_decode($observaciones) . '</td>
      </tr>';


    /* */
}
$html1 = '</table></font></body></html>';
$info = $html . $datoshtml . $html1;
//echo $info;
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->set_paper("A4", "landscape");
$dompdf->load_html($info);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("reporte.pdf");
```

}

Open in Linux[image: Ubuntu]

Open in Windows[image: Windows 7]

Comment: open the file in a text editor on windows and see if there are any error messages in it.

Comment: @Dagon you can see http://pastebin.com/kqwDD70v I not see erros.

Comment: `<H1>PÃ¡gina de Inicio</H1>` that's an error, a valid pdf document starts with `%PDF-(version number)`

Comment: @Dagon As I can solve it? Thus if I is generated by dompdf?

Comment: the h1 is not in the posted code, its getting in to the top of the file - somewhere